# How to obtain the facebook uid of a user in php

Tags: php, facebook, canvas

Hey, I'm writing a canvas app for facebook. I use the command:

```
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
```

To get the userid, but at the first few pages of my app I don't want to require login, but if the user's logged in, I'd like to know what the userid is. Basically I need a `get_login()` command that perhaps returns 0 or null if the user is not logged in. Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing an FBML app, then on every page of your app Facebook will pass a bunch of data in the query string of the page request.  These parameters are all prefixed with `fb_sig`, and make up the validation information for the user.  You don't need to query the API at all.

When you instantiate the `$facebook` object from the standard PHP client library, using something like `$facebook = new Facebook('api key','secret key');`, the Facebook code automatically validates all these parameters for you and stores the result as part of the Facebook object.

As a result, you can simply do the following to determine if a user is logged in:

```
$facebook = new Facebook('api key','secret key');
$fbId = $facebook->get_loggedin_user();
```

If all the proper parameters were received, then you will get the user's Facebook id.  I believe you get `null` otherwise.

Note that if you are making an iframe app, there are other things to consider, as Facebook Connect will set cookies that may not necessarily expire when a user logs out of Facebook.  The signature is always valid though, so if you get an id from `get_loggedin_user()`, you can be sure that it's the right id.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought this was the case, but it wasn't working. After further investigation it appears this wasn't working properly because of the way I sanitized my $_POST array. Thanks!